# Symfony 4 - SQLSTATE[42000] alter table for unknown reasons

Tags: sql, doctrine, symfony4

I'm here because, I need your help. I'm working on a Symfony project, I just finished to modify my DataBase with MySqlWorkBench (I've done this because I have to present the DataBase at the end of the school year). After that, I've executed "Forward Engineer" to send all the tables and columns to the database.

Then, i've just entered this line, to create my entities:

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import "App\Entity" annotation --path=src/Entity
```

Later I put this line line to generate my setters/getters and my Repositories

```
php bin/console make:entity --regenerate App
```

When it's done, I've used those lines :

```
php bin/console d:m:diff
```

And I migrate all to the database:

```
php bin/console d:migrations:execute --up 20190321194410
```

And after this command, I got a ton of errors but they deal of the same thing.

There is this query, I don't know why it's executed:

```
ALTER TABLE school_has_level RENAME INDEX fk_school_has_school_level_school1_idx TO IDX_102C1F10C32A47EE
```

And after there is those errors :

```
In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 79:

An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE school_has_level RENAME INDEX fk_school_has_school_level_school1_idx TO IDX_102C1F10C32A47EE':     

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB serve 

r version for the right syntax to use near 'INDEX fk_school_has_school_level_school1_idx TO IDX_102C1F10C32A47EE' at line 1
```

I'm searching some tips on Internet but I didn't find anything about that. The problem is that, I don't understand where the query is started...

Thank you for your future answer, and sorry for my english :'(

Best regards,

Mathieu